# Getting data from two table with one query

Tags: json, laravel

I have two tables `posts` and `images` and I want to get all the posts and related images with below code:

```
    $posts = Post::leftJoin('images','posts.postId','images.postId')
    ->where('countryId', $id)
    ->groupBy('posts.postId')
    ->orderby('posts.postId', 'desc')
    ->select('posts.*','images.*', 'posts.postId as postId')
    ->get();
```

But the problem is that I get only one image of the post instead of all images because one post have multiple images.

Current Json response is:

```
[
    {
        "postId": 103,
        "text": 'This is the post text',
        "countryId": 75,
        "imageId": 152,
        "imageLink": "C9hGzwVKlOrL.jpg",
        "imageDescription": ""
    },
    ... 
]
```

And I want to change it like this:

```
[
    {
        "postId": 103,
        "text": 'This is the post text',
        "countryId": 75,
        "images" : [
            {
                "imageId": 152,
                "imageLink": "C9hGzwVKlOrL.jpg",
                "imageDescription": "This is the 1st image description"
            },
            {
                "imageId": 153,
                "imageLink": "JHKJdiuIuoi.jpg",
                "imageDescription": "This is the 2nd image description"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ... 
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to get hierarchical/nested data using one query. Eloquent has "Relationships" functionality for that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

In your case you need to add "images" relation to `Post` model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'postId', 'postId');
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$posts = Post::where('countryId', $id)
    ->orderBy('postId', 'desc')
    ->select('posts.*','images.*', 'posts.postId as postId')
    ->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->images; // = collection of all images related to this post
}
```

Comment: I did like this ```$images = [];
        foreach ($posts as $post) {$images[] = $post->images; } return $images;``` and it only show the post images not the post content. I want post with the images.

Comment: Just `return $posts`;